# Need to revert to an older version of wordpress

Tags: plugins, menus

One of my plugins, shiftnav, does not work with the newest version of wordpress I think, how do I revert in order to fix shiftnav? It is currently making "| 500" appear on all of my menu titles

Comment: Really  difficult due to the database changes that are hardly reversible. I'd recommend to drop the plugin, or ask the author (or another programmer) to fix it.

Comment: If you have a DB backup then you should have fair luck with reverting the DB and using FTP to overwrite WordPress with the version of your choosing. I've actually overwritten WordPress without a DB backup before, successfully, but results will vary depending on the versions/themes/etc. However, if you want WP up to date, you will need a more permanent solution sooner or later.

Comment: Are you sure the problem is in Shiftnav? It is supposed to be [compatible to WP 4.4.3](https://wordpress.org/plugins/shiftnav-responsive-mobile-menu/), so not that old.

Comment: I would not advise downgrading as new editions typically include security updates.  Have you tried reaching out to the plugin developer under [support](https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/shiftnav-responsive-mobile-menu)?

Answer (score 1):

In order to downgrade your wp version , first download your desired version from the link below

https://wordpress.org/download/release-archive/

Then follow the steps

1. Deactivate all plugins
2. Logout of wordpress
3. Delete the WP-ADMIN  WP-INCLUDES folders via FTP
4. Transfer the files from the downngraded wp version to your site via FTP **EXCEPT WP-CONTENT**
5. Now login to wordpress , you will be requested to update database , and do it .

You are done.